# Remove certain attributes from a string PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

Hello once again Stackoverflow!

I would like to remove the `rel` and `target` tag and make the url relative.

My input string is

```
<a href="http://example.com/relative/path/" rel="external" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a href="http://example.com/relative/path" rel="external" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

And what I would like to achieve is this:

```
<a href="relative/path">Link</a>
<a href="relative/path/">Link</a>
```

So what I did is:

```
$string = preg_replace("_<a href=\"http://example.com/(*.?)\" target=\"\_blank\" rel=\"external\">_si", "<a href=\"http://example.com/$1\">", $string);
```

But the regex turned out to be wrong. Could someone please explain to me what's wrong and show me the correct solution?

I know I shouldn't use regex to parse HTML, but for just a couple of matches within a string, I figured it would be easier.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/kY5fG3

Comment: Have a try using one of the many regex testing tools available. THe better ones allow you to construct your regex step by step. At a first glance I'd say your regex is invalid: the termination character you chose (`_`) is contained within your pattern...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regexp you have wrong order of following tags (target, rel). This will remove all of them in any order:

```
$string = preg_replace("_<a href=\"http://example\.com/(.+?)\"((\w+=\".+?\")|\s*)*>_si", "<a href=\"$1\">", $string);
```

Comment: This was my answer. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how dynamic you like the script to be, but you could try this regex pattern:

/\s?(rel|target)=".+?"|http(s*)://[a-z0-9|.]+/

It will match the rel and target attributes unregarding of their value, and also the protocol and domain part of the url. Again, if you specify what you want to accomplish, i could suggest a more suitable pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.

```
$string = preg_replace('@<a href="http://example.com/(.*)" (?:.*)>(.*)</a>@U',
                        '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $string);
```

The `U` flag makes it ungreedy, so the first `(.*)` doesn't match too much. The `(?:.*)` is a non-capturing group that matches `rel="external" target="_blank"`, but ignores it.

To make it more robust, you could modify the pattern slightly:

```regex
@<a(?:.*)href="http://example.com/(.*)"(?:.*)>(.*)</a>@U
```

Comment: _false comment, original:_ Although this solution didn't work for me somehow. I would still like to thank you for extended explanation

Comment: @Thew What is wrong with it? I tested it and it works for me.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change `example.com` to my own domain, it's working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out this:

```
<?php
$string = '<a href="http://example.com/relative/path/" rel="external" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a href="http://example.com/relative/path" rel="external" target="_blank">Link</a>
';
//
$string = preg_replace("#<a href=\"http://example.com/(.*)\" rel=\"external\" target=\"_blank\">#i",
  "<a href=\"/$1\">", $string);
//
echo "<textarea style=\"width: 700px; height: 300px;\">";
echo $string;
echo "</textarea>";
?>
```

Your error is in

```
(*.?) that should be (.*)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could easily accomplish this with jQuery over PHP.

```
$("a").each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('rel');
    $(this).removeAttr('target');
});
```

I am not sure what would be the best method to accomplish this with PHP.

Comment: Why would you post a client-side solution when the question is about server-side code? An inexperienced user might use this solution and end up with insecure code where sanitization happens only on the client.

Comment: Like i said, i wasn't sure what the best method would be using server side so i presented an alternative if the user hadn't thought about it yet.